# creation of Model_card in sagemaker pipeline throws "Error when serializing object of type [tuple]: TypeError("cannot pickle 'SSLContext' object")

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have below steps for my pipeline

```
step0: I create my model with my model data
        step1: I follow `RegisterModel` to register the model
        step2: Then I use `CreateModelStep` using step0 model(i.e. step_create_model)
        step3: Then I create a lambda `LambdaStep` step which gives me model_package_arn as output as below also it creates an endpoint, PS: lambda takes input paramter model_name from `step_create_model.properties.ModelName`  and `modelPackageGroupName`
        model_package_arn_ref = step_deploy_model_lambda_and_get_package_arn.properties.Outputs["ModelPackageARN"] 
    and output parameter for 
lambda model_package_group_name_param = LambdaOutput(output_name="ModelPackageARN", output_type=LambdaOutputTypeEnum.String
)
```

if I run this workflow with below condition with the pipeline as below:

```
step_cond = ConditionStep(
        name="MSE-Lower-Than-Threshold-Condition",
        conditions=[cond_lte],
        if_steps=[step_register_model,
                  step_create_model,
                  step_deploy_model_lambda_and_get_package_arn
                  ],
        else_steps=[],
    )

pipeline = Pipeline(
        name=pipeline_name,
        parameters=[
            training_instance_type,
            processing_instance_type,
            processing_instance_count,
            input_data,
            model_approval_status,
            training_epochs,
            accuracy_mse_threshold,
            endpoint_instance_type,
            model_package_arn_ref,
            model_package_group_name_param
        ],
        steps=[step_preprocess_data, step_train_model, step_evaluate_model, step_cond],
        sagemaker_session=pipeline_session,
    )
```

I see the my model package arn and other output in workflow DAG for last one which is lambda.

Now I would like to add create model card as `@step decorator` to use custom function to create the model card [stepdecorator](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/workflows/pipelines/sagemaker.workflow.pipelines.html#step-decorator)

```
@step(
    name="CreateModelCard"
)
def create_model_card(model_package_details, sagemaker_session):
    model_card_name = "TestingModelCard"
    # Get model package details
    mp_details = ModelPackage.from_model_package_arn(
        model_package_arn=model_package_details,
        sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    )

    my_card = ModelCard(
        name=model_card_name,
        status=ModelCardStatusEnum.PENDING_REVIEW,
        model_package_details=mp_details,
        sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session
    )
    my_card.create()
    return f"Model card {model_card_name} created successfully"
```

Then my step for `model_card` lookslike below

```
model_card_pipeline_params = {"model_package_details": model_package_arn_ref,
                                  "sagemaker_session": sagemaker_session
                                  }
    step_delayed_model_card = create_model_card(**model_card_pipeline_params)
```

and then If I add the this `step_delayed_model_card` in my condtition after lambda call I'm getting the error. Does anyone know, what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

new step condition with model_card

```
step_cond = ConditionStep(
        name="MSE-Lower-Than-Threshold-Condition",
        conditions=[cond_lte],
        if_steps=[step_register_model,
                  step_create_model,
                  step_lower_mse_deploy_model_lambda_package_arn,
                  step_delayed_model_card
                  ],
        else_steps=[],
    )
```

The error looks like this

```
Exception: Error when serializing object of type [tuple]: TypeError("cannot pickle 'SSLContext' object")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/remote_function/core/serialization.py", line 108, in serialize
    custom_pickler.dump(obj)
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 632, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'SSLContext' object
```